# CURL Resize image before upload to Imgur

Tags: php, curl, imgur

Who i can resize image before post it on imgur ? I have already tested link like http://i.imgur.com/XXXXXl.png but i need to resize before

```
foreach ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $index => $tmpName) {
    if( !empty( $tmpName ) && is_uploaded_file( $tmpName ) )
    {

        $file = base64_encode(file_get_contents($tmpName));

         $pvars = array(
          'image' => $file,
          'type' => 'base64'
        );

        $timeout = 120;
        $imgurClientID = "xxx";

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Client-ID ' . $imgurClientID));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pvars);

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        $dataImg = json_decode($response, true);
        $link = $dataImg['data']['link'];

    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

CURL is not an image processing library. You will have to process the image in some way, for example using the GD functions:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

There are also many free image processing libraries you can search for on Google.

Answer (score 0):

You can resize using image magick

http://php.net/manual/imagick.resizeimage.php

Comment: Thanks for reply, who i can use imagick with file_get_contents ? `$image = new Imagick($tmpFile); $image->resizeImage(400, 400); file_get_contents($image)` ?

Comment: Check the example, $imagick->getImageBlob() returns the binary bolb of the transformed image.